# Getting text instead of value on change to BoostrapTable X-editable select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I have using `BootstrapTable` with the `x-editable` to build a table that contains a select box of contacts. When a user selects a new value, I have it alert them to what they selected. Using the `editable-save.bs.table`, I am able to get the value associated with selection option, but that is meaningless to users. I want to get the contact name associated with that value. How can do I do this

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cdvtkndu/

```
var data = [{"Contact": 3}, {"Contact": 2}];

$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        columns: [{
            field: 'Contact',
            title: 'Contact',
            editable: {
                type: 'select',
                source: [
                    {value: 4, text: 'Andrew'},
                    {value: 2, text: 'John'},
                    {value: 3, text: 'Liz'}
                ]
            }
        }],
        data: data
    });
});

$('#table').on('editable-save.bs.table', function (e, field, row, old, $el) {
    var new_val = row[field];
    alert(new_val);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dump the source into an array, and then iterate trough it in order to find the row you're searching for:

```
var data = [{"Contact": 3}, {"Contact": 2}];
var _source = [
                    {value: 4, text: 'Andrew'},
                    {value: 2, text: 'John'},
                    {value: 3, text: 'Liz'}
                ];
$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        columns: [{
            field: 'Contact',
            title: 'Contact',
            editable: {
                type: 'select',
                source: _source
            }
        }],
        data: data
    });
});
$('#table').on('editable-save.bs.table', function (e, field, row, old, $el) {
    var new_val = row[field];
    var arrayLength = _source.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (_source[i].value == new_val) {
                alert(_source[i].text);
          break;
        }
    }    
});
```

Look at my correction: http://jsfiddle.net/4qq1yp1y/

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of this. My only issue with this approach is my real table has many fields, some are select boxes and some are not. I don't know how I'd go about determining which ones need to loop over the source arrays. Any ideas?

Comment: You could have another array flagging wich fields are the ones you need to iterate trough and check for it with an if, using also _source as the variable that saves all your fields. (If I understood what you want, if not please correct me and provide more code) Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9ouxeozs/

Comment: Yeah that seems like the best approach as nothing is built into the x-editable library that I can find.